# I have a question about variable release in global class

Tags: iphone, release, global

```
+ (void)findAndCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded{
NSArray         *path               = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString        *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager   *fileManager        = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString        *databasePath       = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB"];
BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
if(!success){
    NSString *resourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:databasePath error:NULL];
}

NSString        *tracePath          = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Trace"];
BOOL traceDir = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:tracePath];
if(!traceDir){
    NSString        *resourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Trace"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:tracePath error:NULL];
}


NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];

NSDate   *today         = [[NSDate alloc]init];
NSString *resultYear    = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
NSString *traceYearPath = [tracePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:resultYear];
BOOL yearDir = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:tracePath];
if (!yearDir) {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:traceYearPath attributes:nil];
}
//[resultYear     release];  ?
//[today      release];  ?
//[dateFormatter  release];  ?
```

}

I'm using global class like this [ + (void)findAndCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded ].
hm,, I don't know NSArray, NSString and NSFileManager are released.

Variable release or Not release ? please advice for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *resultYear    = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
//[resultYear     release];  ?
```

You do not need to `release` `resultYear`. The object returned from the `stringFromDate:` will be `autorelease`'d.

It's usually safe to assume that objects returned from methods whose names do not start with "create" or "new" will be `autorelease`'d. At least with Apple code, but this is a convention for Cocoa in general, so you should also follow it.

```
NSDate   *today         = [[NSDate alloc]init];
//[today      release];  ?
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
//[dateFormatter  release];  ?
```

You need to release both `today` and `dateFormatter`, since you `alloc`'ed them. Always pair an `alloc` with a `release` or `autorelease` in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

yes, and some more:
do not release NSArray * path - it is autoreleased (almost always id returned by functions are).
also do not release fileManager - it is shared singleton object